.NET MAUI Execute Button Command Upon <Enter> by User
I just wanted to know, is there any possibility to bind the  keyboard input to executing a specific button command in .NET MAUI?
I've seen one can apparently use keyboard accelerators for the menu flyout on Windows and Mac, but is this also possible for any arbitrary keyboard input and button of the UI?

Explain it a bit further, what do you want specifically

I simply want to listen to the keyboard and react upon pressing of specific keys on the keyboard. However, not complex keyboard accelerators with two or more combinations, put simply one key. For example, in a specific page I want a specific button to be executed (as in pressed) when the user presses the  key.

I mean you could listen to the TextChanged event of your Entry controls and then trigger your buttons event from there

But what if there is no Entry on the page? Just a couple of check boxes and in the lower right corner a "next" button. How can I listen to  key so upon pressing the "next" button is executed?

@user25033240 Allow me to jump in. There is nothing simple about your task. Every platform has specific solution to your problem. It is best to work it case by case. Generic multiplatform hook to the keyboard is not something you want to implement, without reason. Say what OS you are using, I can give you some advice. But if you DO have Entry, do not think about situations where you DO NOT have Entries yet...

I do not use Entry (it simply does not make sense in my case). I use .NET MAUI right now exclusively on and for Windows, which likely won't change in the foreseeable future.

Did you read this document about Keyboard accelerators?

I've found a solution using SharpHook:
I've created a "KeyboardService" which looks like the following:
public class KeyboardService : IKeyboardService
{
    private readonly IGlobalHook _hook;
    public IGlobalHook Hook { get =>  _hook; }

    public KeyboardService()
    {
        _hook = new TaskPoolGlobalHook();
        InitKeyboardHooks();
    }

    private async void InitKeyboardHooks()
    {
        await _hook.RunAsync();
    }
}

with the simple corresponding Interface for possible future mocking:
public interface IKeyboardService
{
    IGlobalHook Hook { get; }
}

Now upon navigating to the ViewModel using keyboard hooks I'm registering an event handler in ApplyQueryAttributes:
public partial class TestViewModel : IQueryAttributable
{
    private readonly IKeyboardService _keyboardService;

    public TestViewModel(
        IKeyboardService keyboardService)
    {
        _keyboardService = keyboardService;
    }

    public override void ApplyQueryAttributes(IDictionary<string, object> query)
    {
        _keyboardService.Hook.KeyPressed += keyboard_enter;
    }

    private void keyboard_enter(object? sender, KeyboardHookEventArgs e)
    {
        switch(e.Data.KeyCode)
        {
            case KeyCode.VcEnter:
                OnKeyboardEnter();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void OnKeyboardEnter()
    {
        // ...
    }
}

Of course, upon leaving the page one needs to remember to unregister the event handler, since this SharpHook keyboard handler is globally used in the application, e.g. in another RelayCommand in the very same TestViewModel class:
[RelayCommand]
private async Task OnHomeViewAsync()
{
    await NavigationService.NavigateToAsync("HomeView");
    _keyboardService.Hook.KeyPressed -= keyboard_enter;
}

This pattern can one repeat throughout the ViewModels in the application.
However, I have not yet tried if one can effectively use keyboard combinations, such as Strg + Enter or Shift + Alt and so on.
